Rare road movie with the protagonist resembling Philip Seymour Hoffman
B-production road movie, late 80's or 90's probably. Guy in his 40-50s, marred probably (I think that he spoken with his wife on phone), alone on the road. He looks big, or fat, but not extreme, pale complexion and hair, looks like Philip Saymour Hoffman (not Dustin) but it's not him, more like confused-retarded face "Hoffman" (sorry for expression, my English is bad, heh). So, he is driving, I believe white car, trough remote US shithole and on the way he encounters strange characters: stoned female owner of a road motel who is nymphomaniac, and he had sex with her, then crazy hitchhiker and so on... then he gets rid of crazy hitchhiker on some gas stop and run away, but it starts to rain and roads are blocked so he needs to return. That is all I know. It's very hard to find it, because I saw many road movie lists and it was not there.

Not a great match, but "crazy hitchhiker" makes me think of Sally Kellerman in "Slither", (1973), http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069282/.  James Caan abandons her at a gas station when he sees that she is robbing it, and he does run into her again later.

Her is him... hitchhiker is male. He is not mental institution crazy but crazy enough not to drive with him. It's not Slither, unfortunately. :(
But thanks for trying. :)  And, he is also in his 40-50s.

@Vlad Could it be  "Door to Silence" (1991)

Any chance that this movie is called Identity, and that you're talking about Jake Busey?
IMDB describes it as:

Stranded at a desolate Nevada motel during a nasty rain-storm, ten strangers become acquainted with each other when they realize that they're being killed off one by one.

